# If I buy "flushable" wipes, can I flush them without problems?

Tags: consumer-products, hygiene, marketing, advertising, toilets

I know they say "Flushable" right on the package, but are they?  Do they break down fast enough to not cause problems in septic/sewer systems?

Comment: not according to the guy who came to snake my drain.

Comment: Try putting two or three brands in containers with water and let it there for a while. You could measure the rate of decomposition of each.

Comment: @Aleadam: that's what I was thinking of doing. I also thought I should use a couple brands of toilet paper (as a baseline).

Comment: They may be flushable in new construction that uses PVC pipes for the waste line. Older construction with cast iron pipes have lots of flaking metal that snags the wipes and clogs the line.

Comment: I had to call a plumber to snake my toilet after a couple months of flushing "flushable" wipes.  He said they've been a boon to his business.  He also gave me a stern warning about "Ultra-Strong" toilet paper.

Comment: @Aleadam You would have to simulate the same bacterial load found in the sewer mains too, they can work quickly.  But in general if it takes longer than a day to break up, it gets caught up in a filter and removed from the slurry ponds at a municipal sewer treatment plant.  Modern treatment plants will process blackwater to water ready for release in about 24 hours.

Comment: Dear Tester101:  Are you fully satisfied with any of the answers?  If so, could you please add an "accepted" checkmark to one of them?

Answer (score 26):

[INDA](http://www.inda.org/) and [EDANA](http://www.edana.org) are industry groups representing the Nonwoven Fabrics (wipes) industry. They have defined [Flushability Guidelines](http://www.inda.org/press/2008/flushabilityGuidelines_May20.html). The full spec is kept behind a $3000 paywall, but the [Executive Summary](http://www.inda.org/pubs/tests/Flushability_ES.pdf) explains:

> For a product to be flushable it must:
>
> - Clear toilets and properly maintained drainage pipe systems under expected product usage conditions;
> - Be compatible with existing wastewater conveyance, treatment, reuse and disposal systems; and
> - Become unrecognizable in a reasonable period of time and be safe in the natural receiving environments.

Organisations such as [NSF International](http://nsf.org) provide a [certification service](http://www.nsf.org/business/flushability/faq.asp) for showing your product conforms to the guidelines. Once you have been certified, you can display a "Certified Flushable" mark.

Whether a particular product that you see on the shelves is, in fact, Certified Flushable, depends on the particular brand and product.

Alternatively, the manufacturers can self-declare their compliance to the standard ([for example](https://www.cottonelle.com/en-us/faq)).

Comment: I would just like to thank the StackExchange team for giving me the reason to research the self-decapitation of ostriches one night, and toilet-paper flushability the next.

Comment: What did you find in the end? Are ostriches flushable or not?

Comment: @Aleadam: They should be easier flushable after the self-decapitation!

Comment: @Martin true! (at least, the head)

Comment: This is a great answer; and I'm sure a lot of time went into it, but it doesn't really satisfy the question.  A bunch of companies **who make these products** got together to make a standard so they can call their products flushable so they can sell more of their products, and since they say so I should ignore the advice of the guy who spends his day up to his elbows in crap clearing clogs caused by these products? ;)

Comment: @Tester101, you make a fair point. On the plus side, my answer shows that the industry is doing at least some form of self-regulation - the claim of "flushable" has a agreed, carefully-defined meaning, unlike, say, "fresh-scented" or "chi". That doesn't eliminate the risk of bias, but gives more confidence than a unilateral statement. (cont'd)

Comment: The reason for not trusting the anecdotes of the first plumber you meet is that the blockages might be triggered by some other unflushable item (only to be joined by the, more visible, baby wipes) or the cause might be a problem of improper venting/water pressure/etc. making the baby wipes an innocent bystander getting caught up. I'm no plumber, so I am likely to be wrong here, but I would like to see a better counter-reference than "the guy who came to snake my drain".

Comment: (As proof that I am no plumber: I read your comment shortly after I woke up and wondered "What do Dutch shoes have to do with flushability? Oh! Not THAT sort of clog!")

Comment: Er...toilets differ.  Doesn't everyone know of some toilets that never clog, and others that clog all the @*&#$ time?  (At work we have one of each type in stalls right next to each other.)  Calling something "flushable" obviously doesn't guarantee that it'll always flush in every single toilet in the world.

Comment: @Kyralessa: "Flushable" does not mean it will flush away in every toilet (as you said, some don't even flush what they are supposed to), it means that the wipe (in this case) will degrade properly and not cause problems in sewer/septic systems.

Comment: @Oddthinking: my surveying doesn't bring a whole lot new to the question, but you might consider adding a link to the INDA Executive Summary ([LINK](http://www.inda.org/pubs/tests/Flushability_ES.pdf)) of their guidelines and the three point summary of criteria they provide. Now, the *specific methods* of determining that wipes 1) clear toilets and maintain drainage, 2) are compatible with existing treatment systems, and 3) become unrecognizable and are environmentally safe come at a high price ($3k), but I think the Exec. Summary does beef up the answer. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Hendy, that's for the link. I have edited. I'm happy for you to make other edits, especially given some actual knowledge in the field. To my eyes, the biggest open issue is "validation"; that is "How do we know that the these standards for flushability actually correspond to real-world toilets not blocking?"

Comment: @Oddthinking: I removed mention of how I have knowledge in the field (though I know you saw it). I don't want any potential trackbacks. In any case, I am trying to answer exactly what you asked, including environmental impact as well. I just emailed INDA the message found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/H6vWNGaf). I'll probably just post a new answer if I hear back and it contains anything highly informative/new to this discussion. I'm excited!

Comment: Got a response from INDA! The individual who handles these questions is out of the office and will get back to me when he/she returns.

Comment: Sometimes, I wish there was a way in StackExchange for an answerer to credit their upvotes to someone else. @Hendy, if you get an decent answer, I would happily do that!

Comment: Eh -- you answered quite well based on available information, and it was the starting point for my idea to contact them directly! Thanks for the generosity and for getting the ball rolling with your hunting :)

Comment: @Hendy Did you ever hear back from INDA regarding your questions?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Missed your question, obviously. No, I didn't.

Comment: Update. Saw in a news update that there's been a rejection of the "flushable" claim of Nice-Pak products, and googled the subject more generally. [Here's](https://pjmedia.com/lifestyle/2016/10/20/wet-wipes-are-wreaking-havoc-on-the-worlds-sewer-systems/) an article about MN filing a class-action against several manufacturers; perhaps it just took ~5 years for these products to get tested enough to know one way or another?

Comment: @Hendy: In practice, don't blindly believe wipes manufacturers' claims of wipes being "flushable". Instead, trust in what plumbers and sewer authority staff have to say instead.

Comment: @unforgettableid: I am not inclined to accept what individual plumbers have to say, based on the reasons given in [a comment above](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/if-i-buy-flushable-wipes-can-i-flush-them-without-problems/28026?noredirect=1#comment11832_3633).

Comment: -1. I'm unconvinced that INDA "flushable" wipes are necessarily that flushable. [These Equate wipes](http://www.ebay.com/itm/401308625500) are made with some HydraSpun substrate which is lab-certified as INDA "flushable". But the table at the bottom of [this page](http://www.oracwa.org/documents/Wipeoutwipes-ChrisHornbackandFrankDick_Part1.pdf#page=17) seems to indicate that this HydraSpun substrate isn't as flushable as you might have thought. Perhaps that's why [the fine print](http://www.ebay.com/itm/401308625500) on the back of the Equate wipes begins with "USE ONLY ONE WIPE PER FLUSH".

Comment: @Tester101, there is now another answer (which I posted). Do you feel that _it_ answers the question?

Comment: Your example link at the end is broken. Are you able to rectify that?

Comment: What authority is there to prohibit people from using the label "Certified Flushable"? Is there a law? Is it trademarked?

Comment: @Tester101 The NSF is a government agency.

Comment: @Acccumulation: 11 years, and two versions of the Flushability guidelines later... they have a [Code of Practice](http://www.inda.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Code-of-Practice-Final-Second-Edition-2017.pdf) which emphasises when you should say it is NOT flushable, and it leaves the format of the "flushable" claims vague. (Again, paywalls are stopping me from seeing the latest.) As a Code of Practice, I assume the punishments for mis-use apply only to members of the associations. My hunt for a US trademark was in vain.

Answer (score 19):

## Summary

In the US and Canada, if you buy wipes which say "Flushable" on the package, you normally should *never* flush them. [(Source.)](http://www.metrovancouver.org/services/liquid-waste/preventing-problems-pipes/wipes/Pages/default.aspx) If you do, they may clog your pipes or your local sewer / septic system. And a sewer clog may cause sewage to seep into your basement. [(Source.)](http://www.startribune.com/flushable-wipes-can-cost-thousands-to-fix-clogged-pipes/298728221/)

Instead of flushing wipes down the toilet, you can use unscented baby wipes. They're cheaper, [(source)](https://community.babycenter.com/post/a30969995/cottonelle_vs_baby_wipes) and probably stronger, than adult wipes. Afterwards, you can throw them in the trash. [(Source.)](https://www.owasa.org/proper-disposal-of-baby-wipes-and-other-hygiene-items)

OK; that was the summary. If you'd like the nitty-gritty details, please read on.

## Baby wipes are cheaper and better, but are not flushable

Truly-flushable wipes must be weak enough to break down in your city's sewage system. [(Source.)](https://books.google.com/books?id=PM9ZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&dq=weak) They're harder to find than baby wipes. [(Source.)](http://www.startribune.com/flushable-wipes-can-cost-thousands-to-fix-clogged-pipes/298728221/) They're also more expensive, probably thinner, and probably rip more easily.

You might want to consider buying unscented baby wipes instead. When you're done, you can seal them in a plastic bag and throw them in the trash.

But, if you insist on buying flushable wipes, please read on.

## The "flushable" wipes currently sold in the US should not be flushed at all

The fine print on the back of the package of one common brand of "flushable" wipes warns: "Use only one wipe per flush". [(Source.)](http://www.ebay.com/itm/401308625500) But even that warning may be insufficient.

In practice, the word "flushable" may mean that a product can pass through your toilet.

Maybe.

But, even if it manages to pass through your toilet, it still might not pass successfully through the drainpipe in your house or apartment. In fact, homeowners and landlords have spent significant amounts of time and money dealing with "flushable" wipes which have gotten snagged inside pipes or equipment. [(Source.)](http://pdfserver.amlaw.com/nlj/wipes-complaint.pdf)

You really don't want to annoy your landlord by forcing him or her to come and fix a non-flushable toilet full of poop.

Worse yet, if your wipes cause your local municipal sewage pipes to clog, sewage might start to seep into your basement. [(Source.)](http://www.startribune.com/flushable-wipes-can-cost-thousands-to-fix-clogged-pipes/298728221/)

An [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120134629/http://www.newsobserver.com/2009/05/27/64324/now-not-flushable-flushable-wipes.html) discusses the matter. It dates back to '09, but most of it is still valid. The article writes:

> "A lot of people flush Kleenex thinking that it's just like toilet paper," [official Darrell Crews] said. "But I can tell you, Kleenex doesn't break down. You can stir it, beat on it, it's just not going to break down."
>
> It turns out that flushable wipes don't break down either, Crews said.
>
> "Some of them disintegrated a little bit, but a little bit is not good enough," he said. "If it doesn't break down like toilet paper, you probably shouldn't flush it."

## Are there any wipes you *can* flush?

The official quoted above used the phrase "break down like toilet paper". But I don't know what he meant. Maybe he meant "break down just like toilet paper, except slower". Or maybe he meant "break down as fast as toilet paper". Because we don't want to clog your home's pipes, let's be conservative and assume the latter.

Fine. A few years ago, a New Jersey official did some experiments. Back then, he [found](http://hasousa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Rob-Villee-PARSA-Letter.pdf) that the only wipes which disintegrate as quickly as toilet paper were the flushable wipes made by Haso. But, as of May '17, their American subsidiary (Haso USA) isn't fully up and running yet.

#### The Swedish research

There was some more-recent research done in Sweden. Take a look at the table of results at the bottom of [page 17](http://www.oracwa.org/documents/Wipeoutwipes-ChrisHornbackandFrankDick_Part1.pdf#page=17) of "Wipes in the Pipes". The wipes which meet the proposed "GD4 WW" criteria are the least-bad choices.

You 'll want to choose a wipe which won't get stuck or cause accumulation in your home's pipes or your city's sewage pumps. So you should choose a wipe which passes the international wastewater industry's "GD4 WW" criteria for flushability (average pump power-draw increase <1%). [(Source.)](http://www.nacwa.org/docs/default-source/resources---public/2017-02-21mdwipes-testimony.pdf#page=14) Even when soaked for only 30 minutes. [(Source.)](http://www.nacwa.org/docs/default-source/resources---public/2017-02-21mdwipes-testimony.pdf#page=15)

The least-bad choice would be to choose wipes made of "SafeFlush" substrate. But even these take 60 minutes to disperse well. [(Source.)](http://www.nacwa.org/docs/default-source/resources---public/2017-02-21mdwipes-testimony.pdf#page=15) They're still not an ideal choice.

So, in practice, if you buy your "flushable" wipes in the US, you shouldn't flush them. You should throw them in the garbage.

## Conclusion

Most "flushable" wipes sold in the US might not be very flushable at all.

The least-bad substrate currently available in the US is the "SafeFlush" substrate. (It's found in Cottonelle adult wipes, Scott adult wipes, and Pull-Ups toddler wipes.) But it's still best not to flush it.

Haso and Aralar both make substrates which are more dispersible. I don't think these substrates are yet sold in America. Let's wait until they are; then we can investigate and see whether or not they'll dissolve sufficiently in 30 minutes to meet the "GD4 WW" criteria. It looks like they will. [(Source.)](http://nywea.org/clearwaters/uploads/8NonFlush.pdf#page=1)

For now, it's best to throw all your wipes in the trash.

Comment: Edited to remove personal email address, and discussion of the best place to buy products. This is not a shopping forum.

Comment: OK. By the way, I just edited the post to reflect some newer research.

Comment: You have changed the answer significantly - especially in re-defining the word flushable in a special way without a reference.

Comment: I just read [the welcome thread](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users), and my eyes are opened now. OK, does [this article](http://abc7ny.com/archive/9383310/) help? It's WABC-TV Eyewitness News reporting on the results of a Consumer Reports experiment.

Comment: In Australia, the manufacturers are being taken to court by the government for claiming they are flushable. See http://www.smh.com.au/business/consumer-affairs/accc-takes-legal-action-over-claims-cleaning-wipes-flushable-20161212-gt9bdb.html

Comment: Important addition [Flush The Misleading Labels On Flushable Wipes](https://www.acsh.org/news/2018/05/16/flush-misleading-labels-flushable-wipes-12971)

Answer (score 8):

[This website from ThamesWater](https://www.thameswater.co.uk/be-water-smart/Bin-it) (a water management company in UK) states that they are not flushable, and even shows you why.

Other sources tell the same story:

- https://www.lanesfordrains.co.uk/domestic/advice/using-drains-and-sewers/wipes/
- https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/oct/26/uk-water-firms-call-for-do-not-flush-labelling-on-wet-wipes
- [This BBC story](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-46188354) says that no wipes tested so far have passed the UK water industry tests.

Answer (score 3):

### In the UK it depends on the product

The UK Water Industry (WI) has set specification [WIS 4-02-06](https://www.water.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Fine-to-flush-WIS-4-02-06-January-2019.pdf) (set in 2019) for toilet wet wipes which are **fine to flush**.

Any wet wipes certified fine to flush have the fine to flush certification mark on the packet.
[image: Certification marks on the packet: scan to watch our dispersibility demo, certified by UK Water Industry, passed the UK Water Industry Specification 4-02-06]

If you scan the QR Code for the dispersibility demo on this example packet, you are led to https://www.andrex.co.uk/Washlets which redirects to https://www.andrex.co.uk/flushability (Disclaimer: I am not affiliated to Andrex - Other brands are available such as [Saxon](https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/p-saxon-flushable-toilet-tissue-42-wipes/4088600326269) which are also certified flushable under the same WI standards).

The Andrex Flushibility page gives you a video, but don't go on a mobile phone unless you are OK with being forced to accept all cookies.

### In the UK, if you don't see this certification mark, [you must not flush them](https://www.water.org.uk/news-item/leading-retailers-not-embracing-wet-wipe-flushability-standard/) as they can block the sewerage system.

Comment: Can you please reference where it says you must not flush "flushable wipes" without the certification? Is there a law?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisrRogers: I think you  have slightly overstated the "must not". There is no force of law here, but merely a warning against it from an industry body.